# Relative Rotation Between two Quaternions

Tags: quaternion

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to find a relative rotation between two quaternions quatA and quatB, i.e. quatC is a quaternion rotation that if applied to quatA would result in quatB. Is there a command/library in ROS which does this? Will tf be of any help?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10124/relative-rotation-between-two-quaternions/) by [Subodh](https://answers.ros.org/users/541/subodh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-05-31

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a Python version of the [KDL](http://www.ros.org/wiki/kdl) library (PyKDL), which allows you to do all sorts of conversions between rotation representations. An example would look like this:

```
import PyKDL
a = PyKDL.Rotation.Quaternion(x, y, z, w)
b = PyKDL.Rotation.Quaternion(x, y, z, w)

c = a * b.Inverse()
c.GetQuaternion()  # get quaternion result
c.GetRPY()  # get roll pitch yaw result
c.GetEulerZYX()   # get euler angle result in zyx format
```

There is a small tutorial [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/kdl/Tutorials/Frame%20transformations%20%28Python%29) that will give you some more background.

---

Originally posted by [Wim](https://answers.ros.org/users/38/wim/) with karma: 2915 on 2011-05-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try using [tf::Quaterion](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf/Overview/Data%20Types). You need to include the following line in the `manifest.xml` file of your pacakge:

`<depend package="tf"/>`

This should compile:

```
#include <tf/transform_datatypes.h>

tf::Quaternion a, b, c;
c = b * a.inverse();
```

I assume it will do what you're asking for, but you should double-check that.

---

Originally posted by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) with karma: 4954 on 2011-05-31

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6